# Links on Tag page for todays and weeks question return same result

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, navigation

The links for each tag on the [tags page of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) for questions of the last 24 hours and the last 7 days return all tagged questions with the corresponding tag instead of filtering by the specified day.

Example (c#):

[312 asked today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&days=1)

[3570 this week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&days=7)

I seems that the `days=1` and `days=7` are ignored. I expected to get a filtered result with the count of tagged questions displayed in the hyperlink text.

Tags page:

[image]

Result page:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the option like *last 24 hours* and *last 7 days*?

Comment: @hims056: I have included the link to the tags page of stackoverflow. For reference http://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: @hims056: Each tag on the tag page provide 2 links. One for tagged questions of the last 24 hours and one for tagged questions of the last 7 days

Comment: @Jehof no, it's not and if so I can't see it. Most likely some forgotten user script you installed and is now not "working" anymore. Just to be certain, can you please post screenshot of the tag page you see that is "providing" those links?

Comment: Go to the http://stackoverflow.com/tags page, then search "asked today" or "this week".

Comment: This was probably broken when the new search was implemented and no one noticed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : i have included the link to the tags page in my question and comment. I think screenshot won´t provide more information to the question.

Comment: @Pang and Jehof cheers, never noticed those are clickable! Feeling blonde now...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok,i have improved my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I still feel more comfortable with a screenshot, will save people the effort of locating those links. :)

Comment: I wonder if this could be the beginning of the week?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : I have added screenshots

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I didn't know they were clickable either... I've never had a useful reason to want to click on them.

Comment: @animuson yeah... we should have known better though, almost anything on SE sites is clickable.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I also don´t use this links and i noticed it incidentally. But since they are provided on SO they should work as expected, changed or be removed.

Comment: @Jehof of course, no doubt it's a bug likely caused by the new search mechanism as animuson said before. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has not been working for 18 months... If my reading of the codebase is right.

Fixed for the next build.

Comment: Wow... cheers for quick fix and too bad there are no badges for those things! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - The sweet Meta rep is nectar enough for me

Comment: You mean Ambrosia.. nectar of the gods. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - You need to go back to your classics... Nectar = drink. Ambrosia = food. Both, of the gods :)

Comment: That said, I keep getting kicked out over and over here on Meta (i.e. being logged out). You know of anything on your side that might be related?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Meta or Meta chat?

Comment: Meta site. Appears to be fine now, will keep an open eye. :)