# Days-Filter is lost when changing page size or page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, navigation

According to [my other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167095/links-on-tag-page-for-todays-and-weeks-question-return-same-result) (bug) which has been solved, now the result contains the right number of daily or weekly questions of the corresponding tag.

But when i change the PageSize or move to the another page, the filter `days=1` / `days=7` is lost and all questions are included in the result.

I think the `days`-Filter should be preserved, when i want to page through all daily/weekly questions.

Steps to reproduce:

1. [Open Tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
2. Select [722 asked today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&days=1) from C# tag -> Result shows 776 questions tagged
3. Go to Page 2. or change PageSize -> Result shows 420,208 questions tagged

Comment: Bug hunter, eh? :)

Comment: yeah, i´m trying to improve my bug reporting quality :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The days value was not passed on in a single point, causing it to not propagate to the paging code.

Fixed and will be there in the next build.